# Toggling SML comments in sublime 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sml

I installed syntax highlighting for `SML` in Sublime Text 2, however toggling comments
doesn't work.

Does Anyone know how to implement this functionality..?

**Use case:**

```
-> some text

-> (Cmd+/)

-> (* some text *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied the `Comments.tmPreferences` file from the Sass package I use and edited it.  Copy the xml and save it in the same place you installed the sml package.  The line `<string>source.sml</string>` tells Sublime when to use this comment style, for files that have sml syntax.  Edit as needed.  The line `TM_COMMENT_START` tells Sublime to put `(*` at the start of the comment and similar for `TM_COMMENT_END`.  I commented out the uuid lines because I don't know what to put there and it seems to work without it.  I did not test it on sml files, but worked on other syntaxes.  I would recommend talking to the package developer to see if they would add a solution to their code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>name</key>
<string>Comments</string>
<key>scope</key>
<string>source.sml</string>
<key>settings</key>
<dict>
    <key>shellVariables</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
            <key>value</key>
            <string>(* </string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>TM_COMMENT_END</string>
            <key>value</key>
            <string> *)</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
<!-- <key>uuid</key> -->
<!-- <string>7CDCE4E8-3850-4F98-A0A8-AFAE23F4F6E9</string> -->
</dict>
</plist>
```